# Start search using word and stop on HTML tag

Tags: regex, python-3.x, expression

I'm using a python with regex script to do a search in a website in order to get the file name.

Here is my expression:

```
\File Name.*\b
```

And here is result:

```
File Name : AXAOISAOISAOISASAOIASOAIS<br>Format: ABC<br>File Size : 585 MB<br>
```

The problem is, I just want to get the file name like `AXAOISAOISAOISASAOIASOAIS` and in my regex I can find a way to stop of getting the text when encounter the `<br>` tag.

Anyone can help-me to complement the regex to stop at the br tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(File Name.+?)<br>`

The key point is to make `+` operator non-greedy, so it stops after first `<br>`. Desired result is stored in first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3T2oqR/1)

Also, you could wrap `<br>` inside positive lookahead, then you don't need captuirng group: `File Name.+?(?=<br>)`

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/3T2oqR/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(File)\s+(Name)\s+(\:)([\S\s]*?)(?:<)([\S\s]*)$
```

This should give you the file name `AXAOISAOISAOISASAOIASOAIS` as the 4th capture.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go:

```
import re

str = '''File Name : AXAOISAOISAOISASAOIASOAIS<br>Format: ABC<br>File Size : 585 MB<br>'''
print(re.search(r'^File Name\s*:\s*(.+?)(?=<br>)', str).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
AXAOISAOISAOISASAOIASOAIS
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  File Name     # literally
  \s*:\s*       # a colon with 0 or more spaces around
  (.+?)         # capture group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
  (?=<br>)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have "<br>" after
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but when I replace the string with the html source, I'm getting this follow error: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'```

Comment: @PaulMark: That's strange, it works fine for me. What is the result for `if re.search(r'^File Name\s*:\s*(.+?)(?=<br>)', str):print(Match)`